# MySQL Reservation System - Testing for multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a reservation system in MySQL and I'm having a bit of trouble with my query for finding the next available appointment slots.

My days are broken down into 15-minute slots (00:00:00 - 00:14:59, 00:15:00 - 00:29:59, etc.).  Table structure so far:

**appointments table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments` (
`appointmentID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`patientID` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`apptTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`apptDT` datetime NOT NULL,
`apptLength` int(4) NOT NULL,
`apptStatus` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`physician` int(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
`apptType` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`apptLocation` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`appointmentID`),
KEY `patientID` (`patientID`),
KEY `physician` (`physician`),
KEY `apptStatus` (`apptStatus`),
KEY `apptLocation` (`apptLocation`),
KEY `apptType` (`apptType`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;
```

**apptSlots Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apptSlots` (
`startDT` datetime NOT NULL,
`endDT` datetime NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The apptSlots table is already filled with all the 15 minute slots for 2012, as I explained above.

I have a query that can successfully show me the slots that aren't taken in any way (no appointments scheduled at all).

```
SELECT a.*
FROM apptSlots AS a
LEFT JOIN appointments AS b
ON a.endDT
BETWEEN b.apptDT AND DATE_ADD(b.apptDT, INTERVAL b.apptLength MINUTE)
AND b.appointmentID IS NULL
```

What I need to do now is search for appointment slots across multiple physicians, multiple rooms, etc.  For example, if Physician A makes an appointment for 7am - 8am, that time slot no longer shows up in my query above.  But Physician B and C don't have any appointments for that slot, so I need to be able to schedule them.  The same goes for rooms, Room A is used by the 7am appointment, but room B and C are still free to be scheduled.

How can I determine open slots with all these variables?  I know I can test with WHERE conditions for each combination and this works if I need to test for a specific doctor, or a specific room for a treatment.  But, if I just want to see all slots across all doctors and rooms, my query doesn't work and testing all possible combinations individually doesn't seem right, it's just a matter of how to get the right conditions into the LEFT JOIN clause.

Please let me know if I'm being unclear, but I think this is enough info.  If not, I'll add in whatever you ask for!

Thank you for your help, my previous question on here got me as far as my query above, now I just need some refinement.  Ask any questions you need, I'll be here to answer them!

Comment: You can't have one table for appointment slots.  What if Doctor A works 8-5 and Doctor B works 10-3?  Or Doctor C wants goes on vacation?

Comment: It depends on how "typical" a doctor's schedule is.  You might be able to define it in the doctor's table (Doctor A is available Monday 8-5, Tuesday 10-3, etc), then use those constraints when joining to the single apptSlot data.  For vacations, you could have the doctor make an appointment with themselves.  If their availability is more complicated than that, you might want to give them their own rows in the appSlot table.

Comment: @AlainCollins, does that mean you're thinking of slot tables for each doctor, and each resource? Then I would just use my query from above as a subquery really and query each doctor or room and figure out what's available?

Comment: Don't make an appSlot table for each doctor - put the doctor_id in the appSlot table, then add rows for whatever availability that doctor has.  Use a separate table for available resources (rooms, shared equipment, etc).

Comment: @AlainCollins, can you give me a bit more explanation regarding the resources?  I see what you're saying about the doctors' availability, and I'm going to try that this evening.  But you want a separate table of slots to handle resource availability?  Excuse the density of my skull, some of these complex queries and db designs just baffle me!

Comment: "rooms" are just resources.  So are portable devices (EKG, etc), which you might also want to schedule.

Comment: @AlainCollins, so you're just saying an identical table of slots, but instead of a physician ID, you're talking about a resource ID, and all resources will have slots?

Comment: That's it.  The resource_id would join to a resources table, that would include the rooms you planned for, but also the other stuff.

Comment: @AlainCollins OK, I'm so close!  First, make sure you put your response in as an answer so I can mark it as such, I want to give you credit!  Second, how would I find a block of time in the available slots?  For example, I know an appointment needs to be 60 minutes long, so I need to find a block of four contiguous slots for that appointment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here's an answer put together from my various comments:

Note that you can't have just one table for appointment slots.  Each doctor will have a different schedule, including vacations, etc.  The doctor_id should be part of an available_appointments table.

You also have "resources", like the appointment room, or portable equipment, etc.  These should be in a different table (available_resources?), with their own availability and scheduling.

As for finding blocks of time, try this:

```
set @last_time = null;
set @block_size = 1;

select *
from (
  select startDT,
    case when @last_time is null or startDT = date_add(@last_time, interval 15 minute)
      then @block_size := @block_size + 1
      else @block_size := 1
    end as block_size,
    @last_time := startDT
  from foo_appt
) foo
where block_size = 4;
```

EDIT:

Here was my test data:

```
+---------------------+
| startDT             |
+---------------------+
| 2012-11-06 13:00:00 |
| 2012-11-06 13:15:00 |
| 2012-11-06 14:00:00 |
| 2012-11-06 14:15:00 |
| 2012-11-06 14:30:00 |
| 2012-11-06 14:45:00 |
| 2012-11-06 16:00:00 |
| 2012-11-06 16:15:00 |
+---------------------+
```

So there's a 30-minute block, then an hour block, then another 30-minute block.

The inner query does the heavy lifting and produces the following output.  The last two columns are just to maintain the two variables, and should be ignored.

```
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| startDT             | block_size | @block_size | @last_time := startDT |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 2012-11-06 13:00:00 |          1 |           1 | 2012-11-06 13:00:00   |
| 2012-11-06 13:15:00 |          2 |           2 | 2012-11-06 13:15:00   |
| 2012-11-06 14:00:00 |          1 |           1 | 2012-11-06 14:00:00   |
| 2012-11-06 14:15:00 |          2 |           2 | 2012-11-06 14:15:00   |
| 2012-11-06 14:30:00 |          3 |           3 | 2012-11-06 14:30:00   |
| 2012-11-06 14:45:00 |          4 |           4 | 2012-11-06 14:45:00   |
| 2012-11-06 16:00:00 |          1 |           1 | 2012-11-06 16:00:00   |
| 2012-11-06 16:15:00 |          2 |           2 | 2012-11-06 16:15:00   |
+---------------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

The outer query allows you to get just the ones with the appropriate block_size.  You're getting the *start time* of the 4th block.

MySQL doesn't let you set multiple variables at once in a query (you have to do that in a procedure), which is disappointing when trying to mess around like this.

The easiest thing that comes to mind would be to take the 4th period and subtract back to the start of the first period, so the outer query would look like this:

```
select date_sub(startDT, interval 15 * (block_size-1) minute) as appointment_time,
    block_size*15 as appointment_duration
from ( ...

+---------------------+----------------------+
| appointment_time    | appointment_duration |
+---------------------+----------------------+
| 2012-11-06 14:00:00 |                   60 |
+---------------------+----------------------+
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Dear lord, I had no idea you could program MySQL to that extent!  That being said, I think there might be a bug here.  When I run this, I get 3 columns: startDT, block_size, and @last_time := startDT (which is the same value as the startDT column).  Also, it seems to be returning the first slot after the block you searched for. For example: when I search for block size = 4, the startDT column returns 2012-01-01 00:30:00, when there's nothing scheduled in the 12am or 12:15am slot.  Forgive me if I'm missing something, you've been a HUGE help!

Comment: Alain, thank you so much. I finally have a fully working query, and I fully understand it so I was able to modify the final query to show which physicianID was associated with a slot. You've been a huge help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I believe this should do the trick, assuming you have a physicians table.

```
SELECT  a.* 

FROM    apptSlots AS a 

        CROSS JOIN employees p 

        LEFT JOIN appointments AS b 
        ON p.employeeID = b.physician 
        AND a.endDT BETWEEN b.apptDT AND DATE_ADD(b.apptDT, INTERVAL b.apptLength MINUTE)

WHERE   b.appointmentID IS NULL
```

Comment: Tom, I gave this a shot, got 0 rows as a result.  Here's my query, with the proper tables and field names.  Did I mess something up in translation?

`SELECT a.*
FROM apptSlots AS a
CROSS JOIN employees p
LEFT JOIN appointments AS b
ON p.employeeID = b.physician
AND a.endDT BETWEEN b.apptDT AND DATE_ADD(b.apptDT, INTERVAL b.apptLength MINUTE)
AND p.employeeID IS NULL`

Comment: Still nothing, sorry Tom.  Am I missing something that would cause rows to be returned?

Comment: This query should work, but the others make some good points in the comments in response to your question.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll try to dissect this later this evening, maybe I can figure out why it's not working in my database.  I appreciate your input!